# Can't inflate custom view

Tags: java, android

I have a custom view that is called `BarGraph`, and when I try to inflate it, it wont.

```
public class BarGraph extends View {
public BarGraph(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    // inflateView();
}

public BarGraph(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    // inflateView();
}
private void inflateView() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //This line is wrong, can't inflate BarGraph
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bar_graph,this, true);
    hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.hsv_bar_graph);
}
```

The error is :

```
The method inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int, BarGraph, boolean)
```

Comment: you have to set your BarGraph View in your Activity

Comment: you can infalte the layout and add the custom view to it

Comment: To which class your custom components is extends to ?

Comment: the second param must be a view group http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)

Comment: Is barGraph is a custim view

Comment: BarGraph is a customView, it's this one. It extends from View.

Answer (score 1):

Please look on it

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null); // no parent


inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_layout, (ViewGroup) lst_item_view, false); // with parent` preserving LayoutParams
```

please check the logs and work accordingly, surely yours problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter must be a `ViewGroup` and your class is extending a `View`. It needs a ViewGroup because the method `addView` is defined for `ViewGroup` not for `View` (that is the boolean `attachToRoot` does)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bar_graph,(ViewGroup) this.getParent(), true);
```

or set ViewGroup to null.

Answer (score 0):

Extend your custom class to  `ViewSwitcher` Eg:  `customView extends ViewSwitcher` This will solve your problem